# Portfolio react js mapping error for project cards

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

```
    import React from 'react'
    import net from '../assets/netflix.png'
    
    const Porfolio = () => {
    
      const Projects = [
        {
          id:1,
          title:"Netflix Clone",
          desc:"Netflix Landing Page Clone using React JS and Tailwind CSS with Authentication Feature using Firebase",
          imgLink:net,
          codeLink:"https://github.com/codegoggins/netflix-clone",
          projectLink:"https://netflix-clone-13127.firebaseapp.com/"
        }
      ]
    
      return (
        <div 
        className='px-20 py-4'>
            <p
            className='text-white text-4xl'
            >Projects</p>
            {/* PROJECT CARDS */}
            <div
            className='mt-8 flex flex-col justify-center items-center md:flex md:items-start'
            >
            {
              Projects.map(({id,title,desc,imgLink,codeLink,projectLink})=>(
                <>
                {/* SINGLE CARD */}
                <div className='w-[340px] h-auto relative group md:w-[500px]'>
                  {/* OVERLAY */}
                   <div 
                   className='bg-black/80 text-sm md:text-lg absolute flex top-0 bottom-0 h-full w-full rounded-lg overflow-hidden opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 transition-all duration-300'>
                   {/* PROJECT DETAILS */}
                   <div 
                   className='text-white text-sm md:text-lg flex flex-col p-4 gap-3 md:gap-2 items-center justify-center'>
                   {/* TITLE */}
                   <p>{title}</p>
                   {/* DETAIL */}
                   <p>{desc}</p>
                   {/* BUTTONS */}
                   <div 
                   className='flex gap-3 text-sm md:text-lg'>
                      <button
                      className='cursor-pointer font-semibold p-1.5 px-4 rounded-md bg-white text-black transition ease-linear duration-300'
                      >
                        <a href={codeLink} target='_blank' rel="noreferrer">Code</a>
                      </button>
                      <button
                      className='cursor-pointer font-semibold p-1.5 px-2 rounded-md bg-white text-black transition ease-linear duration-300'>
                        <a href={projectLink} target='_blank' rel="noreferrer">See Project</a>
                      </button>
                   </div>
                   </div>
                   </div>
                   {/* Image */}
                   <div className='rounded-lg overflow-hidden'>
                   <img src={imgLink} alt="" className='h-full w-full object-cover'/>
                   </div>
                </div>
                </>
              ))
            }
    
            </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    export default Porfolio
```

> I am getting error to add key , for that instead of react fragments, I
> replace it with a div and give key to it but I am getting error. With
> react fragments I don't get any error but I can't add key to it for
> mapping.
>
> I want the card details to be mapped on all the cards.
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0fT2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return inside mapping and provide a key for the root element.

for example,

```
{
products?.map(({ id, title, desc, imgLink, codeLink, projectLink }) => {
  return (
    <div key={id} className='w-[340px] h-auto relative group md:w-[500px]'>
    //Your code here
    </div>
  )
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
<React.Fragment key={id}>
    some code
</React.Fragment>
```

or remove the fragment and add the key to the first `div` inside the map